# Github action not caching node_modules across jobs

Tags: caching, github-actions

I have a Github action on pull_request, and am attempting to cache node_modules between jobs. I can only see cache working on a job re-run, but not when opening new PRs, even when there have been no changes to my node_modules.

Is this by design?

Each time it runs in a new PR, I see this output in the job:

```
Run actions/cache@v2
  with:
    path: ~/.npm
    key: Linux-build-cache-node-modules-83fc6365b85dd061416fccd5993d48c2003c388bb2184fd57f28d1041d9d261e
    restore-keys: Linux-build-cache-node-modules-
  Linux-build-
  Linux-
  
  env:
    cache-name: cache-node-modules
Cache not found for input keys: Linux-build-cache-node-modules-83fc6365b85dd061416fccd5993d48c2003c388bb2184fd57f28d1041d9d261e, Linux-build-cache-node-modules-, Linux-build-, Linux-
```

Yet, re-running the job will enjoy the cache hit:

```
Run actions/cache@v2
Received 54525952 of 109978126 (49.6%), 51.8 MBs/sec
Received 109978126 of 109978126 (100.0%), 67.8 MBs/sec
Cache Size: ~105 MB (109978126 B)
/usr/bin/tar --use-compress-program zstd -d -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/0bdf436d-9d4d-4397-b8ed-5910ff503949/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/argutopia/argutopia
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: Linux-build-cache-node-modules-83fc6365b85dd061416fccd5993d48c2003c388bb2184fd57f28d1041d9d261e
```

Here is my action yml for reference:

```
name: PR CI
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, develop]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: cache
        env:
          cache-name: cache-node-modules
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-
            ${{ runner.os }}-

      - name: Install Dependencies
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          echo '::debug::deps cache miss - installing deps'
          npm install
```

Comment: Please notice that the cache would be stored only when your job has been run successfully for the first time. After succeed for the first time, it will trigger an post-action of cache, which you can see at the end of the job's workflow

Answer (score 2):

Caching `~/.npm` wont allow you to skip running `npm install`. It will save the global npm cache on this machine so that running `npm install` doesn't incur as much download time, but you'll then still need to build the local `node_modules` for your project.

If you want to be able to skip your install, you can [cache the project `node_modules`](https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/super-fast-npm-install-on-github-actions/) folder as well and skip install on cache hits there, though this could present some issues down the road.

Answer (score 2):

Use advanced alternative caching technique from [this article](https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/super-fast-npm-install-on-github-actions/)

```yaml
- name: Cache dependencies
  id: cache
  uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: ./node_modules
    key: modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

- name: Install dependencies
  if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  run: npm ci --ignore-scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the actions/cache tips and workarounds, caching doesn't work between PRs. With the current setup, it only caches after the first run on a new PR and can be reused in reruns for the same PR. To ensure that all child branches have the cache, you need to create another action that caches on push to your main branch. This way, the child branches that the PRs are based on will have access to the cache.

```yaml
# https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/v3/tips-and-workarounds.md#use-cache-across-feature-branches
name: Cache Dependencies on default branches

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  Cache-node_modules:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows
      - name: Attempt to restore the cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: cache
        with:
          path: ./node_modules
          # The hashFiles function is used to generate a unique key for the cache based on the contents of the package-lock.json file.
          # This ensures that the cache is only invalidated when the dependencies of the project change.
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          # 'restore-keys' are fallback keys used if a cache miss occurs on the 'key' field. They provide a way to restore
          # a cache from a previous state that doesn't match exactly with the 'key'. They are checked sequentially until a cache hit is found.
          # A list of restore-keys is useful when you are restoring a cache from another branch because restore-keys can partially match cache keys.
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-
            ${{ runner.os }}-

      - name: Install dependencies if cache miss
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: npm ci

      - name: Save the cache after installing dependencies
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ./node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
```

Comment: How will child branches have access to this? what do i need to do in child branch

Comment: BTW, you dont need the last step, actions/cache@v3 creates a cache automatically. see section 3 [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#cache-hits-and-misses)